# How to code time window with and if

Tags: python

I just received a code for a time window to start a script in a time window.
If time is ok it prints `True` and if outside the time window it prints `False`.
This is working ok.

Now in the second part of the script, this should only be executed if the time window is
`True` and the input `if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:` is also `True`.
But if I run the script it executes it even if the time window is not True. Any Help please?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import pifacedigitalio
from time import sleep
pfd = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital() # creates a PiFace Digital object
testprocess = None
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if ((now.hour >= 14 and now.minute >=00) and (now.hour < 15)) or ((now.hour >=14) and (now.hour < 15)):

    print(True)
else:
    print(False)


if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/myscriptxy"])
    testprocess = Popen(["/bin/my script"])
    sleep(1)
if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 0:
    if testprocess:
        testprocess.kill()
        testprocess = None
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/myscriptxy"])
        sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your second code block only to be executed if the condition in the first part evaluated to true, you basically have two possibilities:

- Either, move your second code block inside the `if` block's body

  ```
  if ((now.hour >= 14 and now.minute >=00) and (now.hour < 15)) or ((now.hour >=14) and (now.hour < 15)):
      if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
          ...
  ```
- Or store the result of the first condition in a variable and check that variable in the second condition:

  ```
  time_okay = ((now.hour >= 14 and now.minute >=00) and (now.hour < 15)) or ((now.hour >=14) and (now.hour < 15))

  if time_okay and pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
      ...
  ```

---

Also, it seems like your condition for the time window can be simplified significantly. First, unless there are some very strange edge-cases I am not aware of, `now.minute >=00` will *always* be true. But that does not even matter, since you are testing `(A and B and C) or (A and C)` (with `C` being `now.minute >=00`), which can be simplified to just `A and C`, i.e.

```
(now.hour >= 14) and (now.hour < 15)
```

which can be simplified even further, using comparison chaining, to `14 <= now.hour < 15`.